# Serializing shared field

Tags: vb.net, serialization, persistence, static-members

I have one class with a private static (shared, since I'm in VB.NET) field and its associated public static property, since it stores one variable that should be the same to all the instances of this class. So far, so good.

The problem arrives when trying to binary serialize these kind of objects, since this shared field is nos being properly stored and returns to its default value when deserializing.

I suppose this is the expected behaviour, so my question is... how can I make a shared field persistent?

I have read some comments to similar questions that say that this is a bad design, but it really makes sense (AFAIK) in my case, since this variable should be the same to all the object, but can be changed by the user and therefore should be stored.

Can you suggest another way of doing it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: (sorry, I was in a hurry and couldn't complete my question until now)

My Class looks like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class NitrogenController
    Private _active As Boolean
    Private Shared _controlInterval As TimeSpan
    Private _lastControlTime As Date

    Public Property Active() As Boolean
    Public Shared Property ControlInterval() As System.TimeSpan

    'other properies that must be persisted

    Public Function Control() As Boolean
        If Not Now > _lastControlTime.Add(_controlInterval) Or Not _active Then
            Return False
        Else
            DoControl()
            _lastControlTime = Now
            Return True
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

So, the problem is that I can have several nitrogen controllers, but they should all have the same _controlInterval. That's the reason why I used a shared variable for this. But it does not preserve its value after serialization/deserialization. So... any ideas about how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to serialize a class with shared members? Can you show your serialization code and a snip of the class showing one of these properties.

Comment: You might be able to do this by using a non shared property that fetch the shared value. But I would not serialize it with the object, you should concider it as a different object. Like having a config object with a list of items.

Comment: @ Matt Wilko; Why _not_ serialize a class with shared members?? It seems arbitrary to limit serialization to instance members.